# submitting forms in fancy box / codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, fancybox, submit

I am developing a website with codeignite . I have problem with submiting forms in fancy box popups .

Consider this is original page :

```
http://mysite/admin/blog/posts
```

I want to open comments page in fancy box popup

but when I want to delete a comment in popup box , the pop up closes and original page redirects to :

```
http://mysite/admin/comments/delete/5
```

How can I submit or open links in popup without closing the popup ?

Comment: I'm sorry, my brain just seg-faulted. What are you trying to do now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using this url to delete your comments

```
http://mysite/admin/comments/delete/5
```

It will submit your form and reload your page, this is the reason why the fancybox is closed. In this case you need to submit your page with ajax. If you know jquery then here is the helpful link for you http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: The problem is not just about submitting page . I have this problem with links too ( like pagination and so on )

Comment: @user1262319 then you might want to load your content in iframe. See iframe example of iframe.

Answer (score -1):

You might also try this one for delete comment:

```
<a id="cmid" href="comments page url">View Comments</a>
```

Then your fancy box javascript code as like this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){

    $("#cmid").fancybox({
    'width'     : '50%',
    'height'    : '50%',
        'autoScale'     : false,
        'transitionIn'  : 'none',
    'transitionOut' : 'none',
    'type'      : 'iframe'
    });

});
</script>
```

Then you do delete comment. I think this won't close the pop up window.

Comment: It will just load the content of `http://mysite/admin/comments/delete/5` in fancybox and i don't think that's the answer of this question